# How to make label always start from top left in TextField Compose UI

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have a text field with custom height around 400.dp

My requirement is to place the label on the top left in stead of the middle which is the default behavior of the text field.

Below is the current output.

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: The expected output is actually the default behavior, seems you have something in your code that overwrites it. I'd suggest you to add the code you use in the question.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?